# Multiple lookups with a sumproduct at the end

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, vlookup, countif

good afternoon,

Basically I want my end product to be a neat little table telling me how many enquiries for Ext, Int, or Comp have taken more than 48 hours for every month.

It needs to search column F for the month, then column B for the type and then column G for the time taken and sumproduct all the ones that have taken >48 hours....

this is what I have so far, that doesn't work at all!!

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((B2:B1000=AI9)*VLOOKUP((INT(F5:F1000)=X27)+1,F5:F1000,6,FALSE)*VLOOKUP(MONTH(2),G5:G1000,7,FALSE))>"48:00:00")
```

[image]

Comment: Raw data, rather than an image, would be super helpful here!

Comment: Also, that "neat little table" should almost certainly be a filtered *pivot table*. Job done.

Comment: I would first do the 48hr bit - that would limit which ones need checking / calculating...